# vectors constructed with $0,1$ permutation

Tags: list-manipulation, vector

Our desire is to construct $2^N$ vectors with indices $i=1,..,2^N$ with elements by permutation of $0$ and $1$.

For example ($N=3$):

[image: (0,1) vectors]

We write below code

```
Do[Do[Do[Do[Subscript[A, i][j, k, l], {i, 1, 8}], {l, 0, 1}], {k, 0, 1}], {j, 0, 1}]
```

But for the large $N$, this line will not be so useful. How can we produce them in a short way?!

Comment: `Tuples[{0, 1}, 3]` generates the N=3 case.

Comment: and `Tuples[{0, 1}, 4]` the N=4 case, this is a hint!… :-)

Comment: how can I specify a correct index to them?

Comment: Compact: `IntegerDigits[Range[2^n] - 1, 2, n]]`. If a bunch of assignments must be made, use `Scan[]`. I'll leave further elaboration to somebody else… ;)

Comment: How do you want to use the vectors ?

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Exactly what I had in mind but rather something like `a[i_, n_] := a[i, n] = IntegerDigits[i - 1, 2, n]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Getting the form desired by the OP was a challenge, but here goes:

```
vectorPermutations[n_] := Module[{ss, tt, mt},
  ss = Table[Subscript[A, i], {i, 1, 2^n}];
  tt = Tuples[{0, 1}, n];
  mt = MapThread[f, {ss, tt}, 1];
  HoldForm[Evaluate[mt]] /. f -> Set]

vectorPermutations[4]
```

[image]

Edit:
To turn the displayed permutations into assignments, use ReleaseHold

```
In[434]:= vectorPermutations[4] // ReleaseHold

Out[434]= {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {0,
   1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 
  0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 
  0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}

In[435]:= Subscript[A, 1]

Out[435]= {0, 0, 0, 0}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, that OP actually wanted to *display* the `Set`s, but +1 for a non-standard approach all the same.

Answer (score 3):

Building off the comments above:  set $n$ to whatever value you want, and then run the following code:

```
Evaluate[Table[Subscript[A,i], {i, 2^n}]] = Tuples[{0, 1}, n]
```

The `Evaluate` appears to be necessary so that Mathematica knows that you want to equate the results of the `Table` command with the RHS, rather than trying to redefine the `Table` command itself.

Comment: "appears to be necessary" - a look at the result of `Attributes[Set]` should be revealing. ;)